# Hide a Solution with Draft Status

Tags: administration, solutions

I want to hide a solution with draft status from other users, I want that as long as the status is draft only visible by me and by the solution administrators. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do this today. Fortunately, there's an [idea you can go vote](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Br64) on.